# Where do I put downloaded data files?

Tags: python, directory, download, path, package

My Python package needs to download a data file ([cc-cedict](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/export/cedict/cedict_1_0_ts_utf-8_mdbg.zip)) that I cannot include in my package because of licensing issues. The file is large enough that I only want to force users to download it once and have it live somewhere in the local filesystem where it can be found by my package. I may want to treat other external data resources in this fashion as well.

What is the recommended way of doing this? Specifically, is there a platform-neutral way of getting a user-writable directory path where such a datafile can be stored and accessed?

I've done enough research to know that the file cannot be stored inside of the package (I guess permissions would make that complicated even if it was allowed generally).

Comment: Perhaps `os.path.expanduser('~/somedir/somefile.zip')`? See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser).

Comment: That could work.